# Importa variable root desde un modulo a otro

Tags: python

--Tengo dos módulos: CRUD_interfaz.py y CRUD_funciones.py

--En el módulo CRUD_interfaz.py creo una ventana con el nombre **root=Tk()**

--En el módulo CRUD_funciones.py tengo una función que me debe cerrar la venta con la orden **root.destroy()**

--Para conseguir esto he intentado importar de varias maneras desde CRUD_interfaz.py a CRUD_funciones.py:
---- from CRUD_interfaz import *
---- from CRUD_interfaz import root
---- from CRUD_interfaz import(root)
-- De todas las maneras siempre me sale el error: **name 'root' is not defined**

--Alguien sabe qué puedo estar haciendo mal a la hora de importar?

**Edición**

*CRUD_funciones.py*

```
def salirAplicacion(): 
    valor=messagebox.askquestion("Salir", "¿Quieres salir de la aplicación") 
    if valor=="yes": 
        root.destroy()
```

---

*CRUD_interfaz.py*

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox 
from CRUD_funciones import * 

root=Tk() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sin código que mirar, no hay ayuda que dar. Publica tu código para ver las declaraciones reales.

Comment: CRUD_funciones.py

def salirAplicacion():
 valor=messagebox.askquestion("Salir", "¿Quieres salir de la aplicación")

 if valor=="yes":
  root.destroy()

--------------------------------------
CRUD_interfaz.py

from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox 
from CRUD_funciones import *

root=Tk()


root.mainloop()

Comment: No veo ningun `from CRUD_interfaz import *` dentro de `CRUD_funciones`

Comment: Si, porque le importación que necesito es CRUD_funciones desde CRUD_interfaz y no al revés.